# Change a variable on click actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I would like to know how I could change a variable on click using actionscript.

I have :

```
     private var test:int   = 0;

     public function thisIsTest():void{
         test = test + 1;
        }

     <mx:Image left="10" bottom="10" source="@Embed(source='Assets/blabla.png')" click="thisIsTest()" buttonMode="true"/>
```

I would like to add 1 to the variable test each time I click on the button 'blabla'.

The problem is that it only works once.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is output when you add `trace(test)` after the line `test = test + 1` ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method would be to use a `MouseEvent` listener.  You attach the listener to whatever you want to be clicked and tell the listener which function to execute when an event is triggered:

```
var test:int = 0;

image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, thisIsTest);
// Will 'listen' for mouse clicks on image and execute thisIsTest when a click happens

public function thisIsTest(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    test = test + 1;
    trace(test);
}

// Output on subsequent clicks
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

This does mean the image you want to attach the listener to needs to be a display object, like a sprite or movieclip, but this shouldn't be a problem if you're using Flash.

EDIT: Further actions noted in comments.

Import an image into Flash and use it to generate a `Sprite` or `Movieclip` and give it an Actionscript link id (like a class name):

[image: Import image into library]

```
// Add the image to the stage
var img:myImage = new myImage();
addChild(img);

// Assign the mouse event listener to the image
img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, thisIsTest);
```

Comment: Thank you ! My idea is to increase the buffer of my stream by one second each time I click. So I should do that : public function thisIsTest(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    test = test + 1;
    trace(test); netStream.bufferTime = test;
}  ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with stream buffers but if your syntax is correct then yes the `bufferTime` will be increased by 1 with each click.  You can take out the `trace(test)` line as that simply outputs the variable to the console so you can see it increasing for yourself.

Comment: Sorry for this silly question. But how could I define my image as a display object ? Thank you !

Comment: Are you using Flash? If so the quickest way would be to import the image into the project library and assign it an actionscript identifier in Properties (right click the image in the library).  Use the identifier to create a display object in your code, eg: Import the image into your library and use the identifier myImage. In code use `var img:myImage = new myImage();  addChild(img);`  This `img` object is what you would then attach the listener to.  I've updated the original answer to include the steps to do the above.

Comment: I am using flash builder. Thank you so much for your answer, I'll try to follow your instructions.

Comment: As long as you can reference the image you're using, much like you would reference a String called myString (var myString:String = "bla"), you can either use it as, or store it in a `DisplayObject` that can then have the listener applied to it.